# problems publishing webjobs to azure

Tags: azure, publish, webjob

I've created 3 webjobs and have been developing and testing locally using the storage emulator. I'm now ready to deploy and test these webjobs to azure.  when I try to publish, I'm getting this below error:

> the database provider is not specified for this connection string.  incremental database publishing is not supported for sqlclient as well as entity framework code first models

Everything works fine locally, there are no connection issues.

I have a web.config transform set for the release configuration that changes the connection details to the azure version, but I still get this error.

Comment: Can you post the connection string, just to see the format. Make sure you are replacing sensitive information!

Comment: <connectionStrings>
      <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard"
        connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=blahblah;AccountKey=accountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
      <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage"
        connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=blahblah;AccountKey=acountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: this is the format Ive copied from azure itself, how does it know the endpoints for storage, or anything else about it for that matter    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"/>
<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />

Comment: As far as I know, the webjob use the App.config file not web.config file. I suggest you could firstly make sure you have changed the AzureWebJobsDashboard connection string and AzureWebJobsStorage connection string as copied connection string. According to your error message,  it looks like it is related with EF. Do you use EF in your webjobs?  Do you firstly create a web site then add the web application to this web site or directly create webjob in VS?